# Is the function $f(z)=\frac{(\bar z)^2} z$ analytic at $0$? Is it continuous at $0$ and does it satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Tags: complex-analysis

I just want to know: is the function
$$f(z)= \begin{cases}
\frac{(\bar{z})^2}z,&z\ne 0\\
0,&z=0
\end{cases}$$

analytic at $0$?, continuous at $0$?, and does it satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation at $0$?

I am totally lost how to start. Please help.

Comment: The title of your question needs to be MUCH clearer. I'm going to have a go at editing it for you.

Comment: Hint : differentiate $f(z)$ w.r.t to $\overline{z}$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: I have edited the formatting.  I think I have captured the intention of the OP.

Comment: Totally lost?  Do you know the meaning of analytic, continuous, and the Cauchy-Riemann equations?  Do you know any theorems about complex-differentiable functions?

Comment: In general, functions that involve ${\bar z}$ in a nontrivial way are not analytic.  So I would expect it not to be analytic at $0$.  That is not a proof, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function $f$ is continuous at $0$ because $\vert f(z)\vert=\vert z\vert$ for all $z$ and hence $f(z)\to 0=f(0)$ as $z\to 0$.

It is not differentiable in the complex sense at $0$ because $\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\left(\frac{\bar z}{z}\right)^2$ has no limit as $z\to 0$, $z\neq 0$. (This is equal to $1$ for real $z$ and to $-1$ for $z$ of the fore $\varepsilon\, e^{i\frac\pi4}$, $\varepsilon >0$).

On the other hand, $f$ does satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation at $0$. Indeed, using the $(x,y)$ coordinates we have $f(0,y)=f(iy)=\frac{(-iy)^2}{iy}=-\frac1i y=iy$ for any $y\in\mathbb R\setminus\{ 0\}$, so $\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y}=i$ and hence $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$ exists and is equal to $i$. Likewise, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ exists and is equal to $1$. So we do have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=i \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$.

Comment: Well, I learned something -- didn't know that a non-analytic f could satisfy Cauchy-Riemann.  It would be just at that one point, right?

Comment: @BettyMock It only satisfies CR in one point! Not in an open neighborhood of that point.

Comment: Please elaborate I want to know how $|f(z)|=|z|$, I am not getting..

Answer (score 0):

Just as above in Etienne's post, but here $f$ is not analytic at $z=0$ because it is only differentiable at $z=0$ and nowhere else. So there is no open set centered at $z=0$ where $f$ is differentiable so your function is not analytic at 0. Since the limit quotient above does not exist anywhere else then $f$ is nowhere analytic.